# Use notebook for gaming. It's too slow. Which part should I replace?

Tags: games, cpu, gpu

I try use my XUbuntu notebook for some Steam Games. Except for the most simple stuff (e.g. textadventures or non-First-Person-Games) it laggs.

I guess, my computer just isn't good enough. But which kind of? Several options I guessed: (Detailed information to any of these, see below. If you are missing some information, add a comment.)

- no hope at all. I would have to replace so much parts, it's not worth.
- It's the processor. If it's replaced, games will work fine.
- too less RAM!
- I need a graphic card. (Does one fit into a laptop?)

---

## Processor

```
me@mycomputer:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 76
model name  : Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3710  @ 1.60GHz
stepping    : 4
microcode   : 0x40a
cpu MHz     : 1016.465
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch epb pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms dtherm ida arat
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2
bogomips    : 3200.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 76
model name  : Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3710  @ 1.60GHz
stepping    : 4
microcode   : 0x40a
cpu MHz     : 1941.783
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch epb pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms dtherm ida arat
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2
bogomips    : 3200.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 76
model name  : Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3710  @ 1.60GHz
stepping    : 4
microcode   : 0x40a
cpu MHz     : 1290.600
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 4
initial apicid  : 4
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch epb pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms dtherm ida arat
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2
bogomips    : 3200.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 76
model name  : Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3710  @ 1.60GHz
stepping    : 4
microcode   : 0x40a
cpu MHz     : 1474.542
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 6
initial apicid  : 6
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch epb pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms dtherm ida arat
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2
bogomips    : 3200.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

I don't know, whether this is interesting: I have installed the canonical cpu patch.

---

## RAM

```
me@mycomputer:~$ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        3957088 kB
MemFree:         1612888 kB
MemAvailable:    1918788 kB
Buffers:           15280 kB
Cached:           640596 kB
SwapCached:         6588 kB
Active:          1683852 kB
Inactive:         463216 kB
Active(anon):    1491392 kB
Inactive(anon):   168432 kB
Active(file):     192460 kB
Inactive(file):   294784 kB
Unevictable:          32 kB
Mlocked:              32 kB
SwapTotal:       4108284 kB
SwapFree:        3971836 kB
Dirty:               104 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       1489044 kB
Mapped:           280024 kB
Shmem:            218752 kB
Slab:             101612 kB
SReclaimable:      54912 kB
SUnreclaim:        46700 kB
KernelStack:       12512 kB
PageTables:        38976 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     6086828 kB
Committed_AS:    7035280 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      240896 kB
DirectMap2M:     3870720 kB
```

---

## GPU

```
me@mycomputer:~$ lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:22b1] (rev 35) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller [1025:108c]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 117
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 1000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:0b.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller [8086:22dc] (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller [1025:108c]
```

---

Do you miss any information? Just tell me what is needed!

How to speed up my computer to make Games (in their low-graphics-option) make run!

Comment: Generally you can not change both CPU and GPU as those are fixed and not replaceable. You can add more memory but that will NOT speed up gaming. You are missing one obvious though: change the hdd into an sdd. Otherwise get a better notebook :) What does this have to do with Ubuntu though?

Comment: @Rinzwind how will an ssd improve performance when op is suffering from laggy gaming?

Comment: @Rinzwind this is interesting. Since this is already on my list, I'm going to try

Comment: @justinbenge I never claimed it would; I just wanted to add another option for replacing hardware as that was the general gist of the question :-) It will speed up loading times of files so it will speed up the system generally. But a newer notebook would be the option I would pick. Well... I really believe games should be played on a console and not on a notebook.

Comment: I voted to close this question as off-topic. Nonetheless, here are my five cents. Considering the processor it is probably not worth investing in the machine if you use it for gaming. Buying an SSD usually works wonders on general performance...However, I am mainly talking about office work performance here. CPU and GPU cannot realistically (read cost-effectively) be replaced on a netbook and memory is not your main bottleneck.

Comment: @Rinzwind Gotcha (*thumsup) and I will have to agree with rinzwind, replacing the notebook is probably going to be your best bet at this point. All of your specs are very underwhelming and underpowered and (without a decent amount of knowledge in electrical engineering) un-upgradeable

Answer (score 1):

I would say it primarily depends on what games it is you're playing. Your computer is severely underpowered for a lot of triple A games that are coming out in the near future or have already been released.

Inserting a grpahics card won't help as you'll most likely be bottlenecked by your cpu, and load times are probably slow as you don't have much ram.

My reccomendation would be to upgrade to a new laptop with something like an i5, 8gb or ram, and maybe a 1050. Again it all depends on what you want to play.

Comment: Well, triple A is not my goal. I want to play simpler games. And I'm not interesting in "how to replace anything" but in "which part to replace will have the biggest effect?"

Comment: There are not a lot of notebooks where you can exchange hardware. The only ones I know are *laptops* and not notebooks (that is the version that is intended for heavy duty and always on the power supply and not the version you take out of the house. And those already would have good hardware :P)